# Writer or OutputStream?

Tags: java

I'm designing a library where a class should have an ability to be able to convert itself internals into text. Which class shall I use: [`OutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) or [`Writer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html)? And what is the key difference between them (in my case)?

```
public interface Memento {
  void save(OutputStream stream);
  void save(Writer writer);
}
```

Which one?

Comment: Writers/Readers deal with character data and Streams deal with binary data.

Comment: @asgs Cleared up my doubts in one simple sentence. Thank you haha

Answer (score 41, accepted):

An `OutputStream` is a byte-oriented stream. Any text you write has to be encoded as bytes using some encoding (most commonly ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8). A `Writer` is a character-oriented stream that may or may not internally encode characters as bytes, depending on what it is writing to.

**EDIT** If you are designing a library, then if you provide an `OutputStream`-oriented interface to which text is to be written, you really should provide client classes the ability to control the encoding to be used.

Answer (score 21):

Text? `Writer`. It is intended for handling characters, honors encoding.

Stream/array of bytes? `OutputStream`. Works on raw bytes, has no notion of characters, encodings, strings, etc.

Comment: and what's about `OutputStreamWriter`? is it used to convert the byte to charset?

Comment: @UnKnown - An `OutputStreamWriter` is a `Writer` that happens to use an `OutputStream` as the destination. When writing text, it will convert characters to bytes using whatever encoding was specified when constructing the `OutputStreamWriter` (or a default encoding that depends on the platform). For converting bytes to characters, you would use a `Reader`.

Answer (score 0):

1) In many cases preferable can be overriding *toString()* or providing a similar method *to convert ... internals into text*. The *advantage* for user of such method is **flexibility**. For instance, if the consumer of such method can:

- Save it as a part of some POJO to database
- Incorporate it as a field into some JSON object
- Save to a *stream*
- Save it to a *writer*

It can be disadvantage in some cases, e.g. when the text representation is relatively big (like 100 MB) and there are many requests simultaneously that produce such objects. This can require too much resources (CPU, RAM). In such case direct writing to a stream or to a writer can be preferable.

2) If you expect that you object can be used in many different contexts, then it makes sense to provide **both**, saving to a stream and saving to a writer. For instance, *HttpServletResponse* provides both, *getWriter()* and *getOutputStream()*, so that everyone can decide what is better in the his particular case. Or Jackson's [JsonFactory](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory.html) provides methods *  createGenerator()* for *File*, *OutputStream* and *Writer*, giving the consumer much freedom.