# How to find the size of an object in Java Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I'm a newbie in android and python, and I'm trying to establish a TCP socket connection between my android client and a python server. Every time I swipe in my app, I send the swipe movement's direction to the server.

```
//java client
            OutputStream output = client.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(output));

            byte[] msg;
            if(strings[1].equals("swipe"))
            {
                out.write(strings[1].getBytes());
                out.flush();
                //strings[0] contains the movement information in format of:
                //xmovement_ymovement
                //for example: 2.5365_8.5478
                msg = strings[0].getBytes();
                out.write(msg);
                out.flush();
            }



#python server
    #the 1024 is a temporary number I just put in there 
    #because I don't know how to find the size of the data in the java client side
    request_byte = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print("reqeust_byte size: " + str(sys.getsizeof(request_byte)))
    request = request_byte.decode()
    print("Received " + request)

    if request == "swipe":
        movement_byte = client_socket.recv(1024)
        print("movement_byte size: " + str(sys.getsizeof(movement_byte)))
        movement_str = movement_byte.decode()
        x_movement, y_movement = movement_str.split("_")
        print("x: " + x_movement)
        print("y: " + y_movement)
        swipe(float(x_movement), float(y_movement))
```

When a simple button press is done and a single data is sent, the code works fine, but when I swipe and a lot of data is being sent in a short amount of time to the server, the data gets mixed up and turns unpredictable.

Now, as this post [Receiving end of socket splits data when printed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641840/receiving-end-of-socket-splits-data-when-printed) says, I know that I need to build a protocol that delineates messages, but on the Java client side, I can't get the size of the data I'm trying to send, so I'm stuck here.

This post [In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object#52682) says I can find size of objects by using java.lang.instrument package, but I can't import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation in android studio. Is there another way to find the size of an object in android studio?