# performance and size limitations on HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream.print(string) vs getWriter(String)

Tags: java, httpresponse

For a web project I'm writing large sections of text to a webpage(table) or even bigger (could be several MB) to CSV files for download.
The java method dealing with this receives a StringBuilder content string, which originally (by the creator of this module) was being sent char by char in a loop:

response.getOutputStream().write(content.charAt(i)).

Upon questioning about the loop, the reason given was that he thought the string might be too big for writing in one go. (using java 1.6).
I can't find any size restrictions anywhere, and then also the question came which method to use instead: print() or getWriter()?
The data in the string is all text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He assumed wrong. If anything it's inefficient, or at least useless to do that one character at a time. If you have a `String` in memory, you can write it out at one go without worrying.

If you're only writing text, use a `Writer`. `OutputStream` is for binary data (although you can wrap it in an `OutputStreamWriter` to convert between the two). See [Writer or OutputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223760/writer-or-outputstream)