# Decoding base64 data and not able to download as a file

Tags: java, java-8, base64

Am getting base64 encoded data as `String` format. Am trying to decode the base64 and want to download as a file. I have commented the below few lines of code, where am getting error out of those line.

Am not sure how to decode the data.

```
String contentByte=null;
for (SearchHit contenthit : contentSearchHits) {

    Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = contenthit.getSourceAsMap();
    fileName=sourceAsMap.get("Name").toString();
    System.out.println("FileName ::::"+fileName);
    contentByte =  sourceAsMap.get("resume").toString();

}
System.out.println("Bytes --->"+contentByte);

 File file = File.createTempFile("Testing",".pdf", new File("D:/") );
 file.deleteOnExit();
 BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
  out.write(Base64.getDecoder().decode(contentByte)); //getting error on this line
```

Please find the below compilation error am getting.

`The method write(int) in the type BufferedWriter is not applicable for the arguments (byte[])`

Am using Java 8 version

Comment: *what* error? Please post the error you get into your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Writer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html)s are used for writing characters, not bytes.  To write bytes, you should use some flavor of [`OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html).  See [Writer or OutputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5223760/3920048)

But if all you want is to write a byte array to a file, `Files` class provides a  [Files.write](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-byte:A-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) method that does just that:

```
byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(contentByte);
Files.write(file.toPath(), bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Example {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String contentByte="Simple text send from server";
    byte[] bytes = 
    Base64.getEncoder().encode(contentByte.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    //Data received by you at server end(base64 encoded data as string)
    contentByte = new String(bytes);

    System.out.println(new String(bytes));

    BufferedWriter out = null;
    System.out.println("Bytes --->"+contentByte);
    try {
        File file = File.createTempFile("Testing",".pdf", new File("/tmp/") );
       // file.deleteOnExit(); // this line will remove file and your data will not going to save to file. So remove this line.
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        byte[] decodedImg = 
      Base64.getDecoder().decode(contentByte.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        out.write(new String(decodedImg)); //getting error on this line

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(out!=null)
        {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
   }
 }
```

Might above solution with help you.

Comment: You should learn about the [`try`-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html)…